# Set of UIImageView.Image re-positions parent view

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UIView and added a UIImageView as child to it. I later change the position of the UIView via another UIButton event.

If I change the image of the UIImageView the UIView  - inc. all shields - moves back to the initial position.

Could anyone maybe explain me what is going on here :-D How do I keep the new position of the UIView ?

[Here a image screen I took to visualize the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v88VS.png)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var number: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var popup: UIView!

    @IBAction func openPopup(sender: UIButton) {
        self.popup.center = sender.center
        //old position: (190.5, 124.0) - new Position: (173.0, 414.0)
    }

    @IBAction func updateImage(sender: UIButton) {
        self.number.image = UIImage(named: "img-1")
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I found out that above code works if I deactivate autolayout. Here is a solution to do this with auto layout: 
[Auto Layout center UIView above another UIView at its center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720197/autolayout-center-uiview-above-another-uiview-at-its-center/33720665#33720665)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that above code works if I deactivate "Use Auto Layout" in Interface Builder Document section at tab File Inspector.

In addition here is a working solution to the issue using auto layout and constraints:

[Auto Layout center UIView above another UIView at its center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720197/autolayout-center-uiview-above-another-uiview-at-its-center/33720665#33720665)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of that? Did you check by logging `popup.frame.origin` after `updateImage` being called? Have you properly set `clipsToBounds` and `contentMode` properties for `number` uiimageview?

Comment: that is interesting the popup.frame.origin is always the same but the UIView moves visually I can see that in Simulator... Seems to be something wrong with self.popup.center

Comment: Have you tried to set `number.clipsToBouds = true` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: just tried it. it does not help. I also added prints to the functions: DidLoad: (113.0, 43.0) - openPopUp: (95.5, 333.0) - updatePosition: (95.5, 333.0)

Comment: When you have a UIImageView, you have to inform how you want to render your image in it. For that purpose, you have to set the `contentMode` property of your UIImageView. Try to set `number.contentMode = .ScaleToFit` in `viewDidLoad`. In this case, your image will fit your UIImageView. If your image is bigger than your UIImageView and you don't set this property, your image will appear out of the bounds (except if you set `number.clipsToBounds = true` ). Please read [the apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/) for more details.

Comment: yep... i set this in storyboard to center directly in inspecter. i also did it again in viewdidload. no changes :-( i feel like this is a bug

Comment: If you have set `Center` and not `ScaleToFit`, it's normal it doesn't work, `Center` doesn't resize the image. If you want to center and resize to fit your image view, you have to use `ScaleToFit` .

Comment: I do not want to resize the image... this issue is that the parent view changes position if I change the image in the ImageView. If you have Xcode    handy try to use above code and you will see it.