# Auto Layout center UIView above another UIView at its center

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a `UIView` (`popup`) and multiple `UIButton`s (`sender`). If I touch the `sender` I would like to center the `popup` at the coordinates of the `sender`.

However, as of *Auto Layout* the `popup` always moves back to the initial position at refresh. I understand that I have to use constraints and change those programmatically.

Unfortunately I don't know how I can adjust below code with constraints. Especially as the `popup` is larger as the `sender`.

Could anybody give me some advice on how to move `UIView`s center at sender's center with *Auto Layout* enabled ? Thanks!!

Here is a screen image of below code that shows the issue:

[image: screen image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var number: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var popup: UIView!

    @IBAction func openPopup(sender: UIButton) {
        self.popup.center = sender.center
        //old position: (190.5, 124.0) - new Position: (173.0, 414.0)
    }

    @IBAction func updateImage(sender: UIButton) {
        self.number.image = UIImage(named: "img-1")
    }
}
```

Here is what I have so far, but I don't know if this is correct and what type of `NSLayoutConstraint` I have to use to achieve this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var id = 1
    @IBOutlet weak var number: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var popup: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var popupy: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var popupx: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBAction func openPopup(sender: UIButton) {

    popupx.constant = reposition(popup, position: sender.center).y
    popupy.constant = reposition(popup, position: sender.center).x

    }

    @IBAction func updateImage(sender: UIButton) {
        if id == 1 {
            id = 2
        }else {
            id = 1
        }

        self.number.image = UIImage(named: "\(id)")

    }


    func reposition (element: UIView, position: CGPoint)->CGPoint
    {
        var p = CGPoint()

        p.x = position.x - (element.frame.size.height / 2 )
        p.y = position.y - (element.frame.size.width / 2)

        return p
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to center your view relative to different views over time, one way to do that is to add and remove constraints as needed.

The following code creates `NSLayoutConstraint`s to center the view relative to another view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var boxView: UIView!
    var boxCenterX: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var boxCenterY: NSLayoutConstraint?

    func centerBoxOnView(v: UIView) {
        // Remove previous constraints on center, if any
        boxCenterX?.active = false
        boxCenterY?.active = false

        boxCenterX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: boxView, attribute: .CenterX,
            relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: v, attribute: .CenterX,
            multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        boxCenterX?.active = true

        boxCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: boxView, attribute: .CenterY,
            relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: v, attribute: .CenterY,
            multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        boxCenterY?.active = true

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Start box at center of screen
        centerBoxOnView(self.view)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(button: UIButton) {
        centerBoxOnView(button)
    }
}
```

---

When you set up the constraints for the `boxView` (the view you are moving around), make sure the `centerX` and `centerY` constraints you create in the Storyboard are marked as *Placeholder* so that they will be removed at build time and not interfere with the constraints created in code.

[image: setting placeholder constraint]

---

If you want the view to be animated into place, replace:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

with:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly... Thank you very much. I try to learn by this example ... The auto layout think drives me crazy :-)

Comment: Auto Layout is very powerful and worth getting to know, especially with all of the different sized devices Apple keeps introducing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing `self.popup.center` you should make an `IBOutlet` for the `layoutconstraint` and change the `constant` of that constraint to place the popup.

Alternatively you can try setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` and using `.frame =` to change the position. That should translate the frame changes to auto layout constraints. This might create issues as you already have auto layout constraints active that conflicts with the new ones though so I would recommend going with the IBOutlet for constraints solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I updated my code with what I think how it should work. But don't know what kind of NSLayoutConstraint I need for this